# Sorting algorithm Java from Python code

Tags: java, python, sorting, processing, color-space

I've been trying to convert this Python code to Processing / Java. I don´t get it.

```
def step (r,g,b, repetitions=1):
    lum = math.sqrt( .241 * r + .691 * g + .068 * b )
    h, s, v = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r,g,b)
    h2 = int(h * repetitions)
    lum2 = int(lum * repetitions)
    v2 = int(v * repetitions)
    return (h2, lum, v2)

colours.sort(key=lambda (r,g,b): step(r,g,b,8) )
```

This is Alan Zucconi's code from his Website: [The incredibly challenging task of sorting colours](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/09/30/colour-sorting/).

This is what I have so far:

```
color [] colours = new color[1000];
float lum;
int repetitions = 0;

void setup() {
  size(1024, 500);
  // pick 1000 random color and put in array
  for (int i=0; i<colours.length; i++) {
    colours[i]= color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
  }
  printBar(0);  


  //simple rgb sort
  colours = sort(colours);
  printBar(50);

  // step sort
  for (int j=0; j<colours.length; j++) {
    lum = sqrt(.241 * red(colours[j]) + .691 * green(colours[j]) + .068 * blue(colours[j]));
int h2 = int(hue(colours[j]) * repetitions);
int lum2 = int(lum * repetitions);
int v2 = int(brightness(colours[j]) * repetitions);
//I am stuck.......

}
  printBar(100);
}

void draw() {
}

void printBar(int step) {
  //show all the random colors in a bar
  for (int j=0; j<colours.length; j++) {
    //strokeWeight(2);
    stroke(colours[j]);
    line(j+5, 20+step, j+5, 50+step);
  }
}
```

I know there will be some problem with HSB and HSV color systems, but I will figure that out. What I dont get is the stepsorting line in Python.
Any Ideas ? Thank you

Comment: What is exactly the problem you're facing? Where is your code going wrong?

Comment: Last line of Python code is the problem, don´t know how to translate it to java. This actually returns a perceptually nice sorting. Shown on the website.

Comment: Take a look at [Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) method and java [Comparators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), which btw can be implemented using lambdas for java>=1.8

Answer (score 0):

Taking a step back, you should **not** try to translate code line-by-line. Similar to how a translator doesn't translate from one language into another word-by-word. Instead, a translator will take a whole sentence, or a whole paragraph, or a whole book, think about the intent of the original words, and then try to replicate that intent in the target language.

That's how converting code works as well. You need to take a step back and understand what the code is doing in the first place. Then you need to write code that does the same thing in your target language.

For example, looking at this line:

```
colours.sort(key=lambda (r,g,b): step(r,g,b,8) )
```

Before you can write Processing code that does this, you need to understand exactly what it's doing. Note that the `step()` function itself does not sort anything. It's converting an RGB value into a different value that's easier for sorting. From the article you linked:

> To dampen the impact that sorting on the first component has, we can reduce the colour space from a float value between 0 to 1, to an integer from 0 to 7. By doing this, much of the noise is removed.

So your `for` loop already looks wrong, unless you're planning on converting the entire array first or something.

If I were you, I would try to [break your problem down into smaller steps](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and then take those steps on one at a time. For example:

- Can you write a `step()` function that converts an RGB value into a converted value? Try running the original code with a few examples, and then running your code with those same examples. Do you get the same thing?
- Can you write an example that uses `Collections.sort()` or `List.sort()` to sort RGB values?
- Finally, can you write an example that combines the two and uses `Collections.sort()` or `List.sort()` to sort RGB values according to their converted values?

Then if you get stuck on a specific step, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a more specific technical question. Good luck.

Comment: thank you for your advise, you are right, direct translation is maybe no good idea. I figured aout the function, some mistakes as the python colors are all value 0-1. And I sorted them following their hues which gives the step effect.

Comment: What I still have not understood is the Python sorting line. Whithout the function would it sort first the R, then G, then the B Value ?  I could only do this in java with the "Comparator.thenComparing()" method which looks a bit scary. Will try to do this with some additional arrays and copying parts of them.

Comment: @OK707 Why would you need the `Comparator.thenComparing()` method? You can use your own `Comparator` that compares the values however you want.